# How to send data from my form to webservice?

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I need to send some data from my form in html to webservice. (For do this, i need to do the operation of POST)

I have seen research that I can transmit information using php cURL. But in all examples, i don't view to send data to webservice, only to file php that print $_POST variable.

I have this webservice: http://192.168.1.1/fastfood/event/attendee (example)
And i try to send data in an array.

For example i try to send: `attendee = array( 'name' => $_POST['name'] , 'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'] , 'address' => $_POST['address'] );`

Then, the web service takes out the array data. ¿How to do this?

UPDATE 1:

This is my code that i'm doing now... But don't work :(

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$attendee = array(
    'name' => "$name",
    'lastname' => "$lastname",
    'address' => "$address"
);

$url_target = 'http://192.168.1.1/fastfood/event/attendee';
//$header = array('Content type: multipart/form-data');
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';
$userpasswd = "$user:$pass";

$ch = curl_init($url_target);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpasswd);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_target);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attendee);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $getInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

The variable $result return me a FALSE, and the variable $getInfo return me a http_code = 500, Content-Type = Null.

Reading the documentation of cURL when i send a data like a array, the content type should be a "multipart/form-data" but, also, don't work for me.

Comment: you can point your from to a php file and that php file can send a request to the web-service via a "POST" operation using cURL.

Comment: @Shaheer Uuhhmm this is the way. But, how to do this?... now i'm writing my php script. But, my webservice don't received the data :( .. When my webservice received this data, show in a table autommatically. But don't show...

Comment: First , Make sure that this web-service supports it (they can prevent external requests easily). Second , read this http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php . Good luck

Comment: @OfirBaruch can yoy give me a example?.. I made a code but I did not send the data :S I don't know I'm doing wrong. I have updated my post.

Comment: If you get `FALSE` and `http_code=500` the URL may not allow sending external requests OR wrong login details. (500 http code means Access Forbidden)

Comment: @Ofir Baruch .. Maybe this is a problem, because when i change the $user and $pass, and this params pass to CURLOPT_USERPWD always return me TRUE. When should be FALSE(if the login is incorrect). Ok, this is already confusing.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with that web-service

Comment: @OfirBaruch OK.. I forgot the step of my login. Because, i have a page where i sign in to the site and then, other page where i can view the data. I update my code. however. When i send the data doesn't work.

Comment: That's a problem because you need to include in your script another piece of code which logs in that webservice and not you to login.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Uuhhmm?.. I need to register the web service? And not to register first? .. What do you mean by that? Because, once commented that even if you change my username and password, you rarely get $getinfo_1 http_code = 200 and $ result_1 an empty string where it says: Evaluating ...

Comment: @OfirBaruch I update my code!.. I have (in the first page) a login with my user and pass, then i redirect to the other page and then, i go to the page when i can view the data. But, always fail in the last lines. (http_code=500) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Here is the data we will be sending to the service
  $data = array(
    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
    'lastname' => $_POST['last_name'],
    'address'  => $_POST['address']
  );  


  $curl = curl_init('http://192.168.1.1/fastfood/event/attendee');


  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //Choosing the POST method
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/helloservice.php');  // Set the url path we want to call
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $some_data);  // Insert the data

  // Send the request
  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  // Free up the resources $curl is using
  curl_close($curl);

  echo $result;
```

Written by Chad Lung at [GiantFlyingSaucer](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2125)

Comment: thanks!.. this code is very similar to what I've been doing .. This example helped me a lot

Comment: only one question, why the param of curl_init (The URL of the service) is diferent the param of CUROPT_URL (A php script)?
What is the different?

Comment: So.. i need to repeat the url of my web service??

Comment: If i'm not mistaken - yes. A simple way to check it is trying it out. play with the code :)

Comment: UUhhmmm don't work for me :( ... I'm Updating my post rigth now with my code. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.